# Excel file does not open due to circular references

Tags: excel, circular-reference

I have an excel file which includes multiple tabs. In each tab, there are functions, vlookups and figures, etc. The file suddenly closed and attempts to open it was not successful.

I am using Microsoft 365.

The error message that I receive when trying to open the file:

"There are one or more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly. This might cause the to calculate incorrectly. Try removing or changing these references, or moving the formulas to different cells."

What I have tried so far:

1. Repair office.
2. Checking if the file opens on another computer: it did not open.
3. In new excel file: go to file/options/formulas/circulation options/select to manual. The go to target file, open using "open and repair" option. Select extract data. Select recover formulas.

I really appreciate any help

Comment: Try opening Excel in Safe Mode; then open the file from within Excel

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks Ron. I opened a new excel in safe mode and tried opening my file from within the new file. I received the following security notice: "Microsoft has identified a potential security concern. Automatic updates of links have been disabled. If you choose to enable automatic updates of links, your computer may no longer be secure. Do not enable this content unless you trust the source of this file". It gives me the option to Enable or Disable. I tried both of them and the file did not open. The error message for circular references did not appear this time.

Comment: At this point, unless someone comes up with something that works, I suggest you contact Microsoft Office 365 support. I contacted them a few years ago about some issue, and they were quite helpful.  If I recall correctly, I started out with electronic communication, but eventually got to an intelligent support human being.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks Ron, I will contact them to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, that's really frustrating (I know, I've been there). Second, what often works is to disable Excel's automatic formula checking temporarily. Open a blank file in Excel. Then go to File -> Options -> Formulas -> Calculation options -> then switch it from automatic to manual. That should stop Excel from checking for the error and hence from preventing you from opening your file. [image: excel circular error edit]

Comment: Thanks a lot Signe, it it definitely frustrating! after switching calculation options to manual, I tried to open the file in the two following ways: 1. in new file open my target file: nothing happened, the file did not open and did not give any error messages. 2. tried opening the target file directly by double clicking on it. The file gave the same error message mentioned in the post and did not open.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this was asked.  And it just happened to me this morning.  But the solution to open a new document and adjust the calculations to manual did not work.

I tried opening the file in another software to see if I salvage any of the data.

What ended up working to recover the file, was trying to open the file in Internet Explorer.  This gave me an option to save the file, which it then opened up the file in excel.  When it opened the file, it still gave me the same error message about the file containing circular references.  But this time it let me open the file so I can delete out the circular reference.

I then made sure to save the file in another location and verify it could successfully open.